# Uncle blocks got generated during the mining process with only one node[one miner]?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

In order to increase the speed to mining, I edit some code in **consensus.go** to reduce the speed of increasing the difficulty of mining. Somehow, when I have my speed of 20 per block, I found that the transaction will be stuck in pending status sometimes and it will never be mined by the miner. In addition, based on the mining info, the block with the corresponding transaction seems to become the uncle block.

Therefore, does anybody know what is going on here and what is the problem?

And also, I found the miner always mine two blocks at the same time. 
My guess is that 2 blocks are mined at the same time and since mining a transaction will take a bit of time, so the block with the pending transaction will be considered as the uncle block because the new block is appended to the chain quicker.